# Declaring stored procedures header and body separately

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, stored-procedures

I'm writing stored procedures in SQL Server 2008. I need to create two procedures which will use each other.

Procedure A executes B and B executes A.

So I suppose I have to declare headers of procedures firstly. I've searched over internet but I can't find the answer how can I make it.

So, my question is: how can I declare header and body of stored procedure separately in SQL Server 2008?

Comment: If a executes b which then executes A aren't you going to get into an infinite loop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't separate them but you can create a SP that calls another SP that not yet exist.

When you run this

```
create procedure TheFirst as
begin
  exec TheSecond
end
```

and SP TheSecond does not exist you will get a message:

> The module 'TheFirst' depends on the missing object 'TheSecond'. The
>   module will still be created; however, it cannot run successfully
>   until the object exists.

Update:

To avoid the messages you can first create an empty proc and add the code later in the script.

```
create procedure ProcB as

go

create procedure ProcA as
begin
  exec ProcB
end

go

alter procedure ProcB as
begin
  exec ProcA
end
```

Comment: Ok, that a pity. Thank for answer. I will check it in the evening if its correct.

Comment: @nosbor Why is that a pity? It means that it will work anyway. Or where you looking for the IntelliSense stuff to work? If so you can create your SP's with no code. `create procedure yyy @ID int as` and then use `alter procedure yyy ...` when you want to add the code.

Comment: Because as you said when you run the script which is creating database you receive warnings. But if alter proc will work without warnings it will suits me.

Comment: A warning is not an error message and, since you are doing this intentionally, can be ignored.

Comment: Maybe but it not looks great when you have a lot of warnings in your script.